# PHPでidを持たせてページ遷移したい

Tags: php, mysql

ニュースサイトを作っているのですが、クリックした記事に飛びたいので、idを持たせる必要があるのですが、どのように書けば良いのか分からずにいます。

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsapp";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php 
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<a href="apps.php?page=1?id=' . $row["id"] .'">'.'<input type="button" value="Apps">'.'</a>';
        break;
    } 
?>
```

apps.phpに遷移した時に各記事にidを持たせて遷移させたいです。

```
<?php
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo'<dt class="news-date">'.$row["create_date"].'</dt>';
        echo '<dd class="news-description"><a href="content.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">' .mb_substr($row["title"],0,10)."...". '</a>';
        echo "<hr>";
        break;
    }
    $pdo = null;
?>
```

以下にapps.phpの記載

```
//apps.php
<?php 
            define('NEWS_LIST', 5);
            $news_start = (intval($_GET['page']) - 1) * NEWS_LIST;
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cs_academy;charset=utf8", "root", "");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsapp WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY create_date DESC";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach($results as $row) {
                $news_id = $row['id'];
                echo '<dt>';
                echo $row['create_date'];
                echo '</dt>';
                echo '<dd class="news-title">';
                echo $row['title'];
                echo '</dd>';
                echo '<a href="content.php?id">';
                echo '<dd class="news-description">';
                echo mb_substr($row['content'], 0, 150);
                if (mb_strlen($row['content']) > 150) {echo ' ...';}
                echo '</dd>';
                echo '</a>';
                echo'<hr>';
            }
```

以上のメソッドでは、しっかりidを持って、content.phpに遷移しているのですが、
apps.phpに遷移する際にもidを持ってページ遷移させるためには、どのような記述が必要でしょうか？

Comment: page=1?id= → page=1&id= GETパラメータが2つ以上あるときは&でつなげてください

Comment: そもそも要件の説明がまったく不足しています。おそらくデータベース上はニュース記事一つ一つにidが振られていることは想像がつきますが、ソースからは遷移元ページ（名称不明。ボタンの一つのみ表示する画面？）から app.php に対して何の情報を持ち込みたいのかよくわかりません。app.php では DB を読み込んで foreach ループで `$news_id` を得ていますから、遷移元から連携すべきデータなどなさそうに見えます。もしかして foreach 内8行目の `echo  '<a href="content.php?id">';` の url パラメータに `$news_id` を付け忘れているというオチでしょうか？ 遷移元から連携するのは `page` だけで良いのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@naga3 氏のコメントにもあるとおり、http get メソッドで複数のパラメータを渡すときは`&`で区切ります。たとえば以下のコードでいかがでしょうか。

なお `foreach` 最後に常時 `break` を置く目的がよくわかりませんが、そのままにしてあります。

```
<?php 
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<a href="apps.php?page=1&id=' . $row["id"] .'">'.'<input type="button" value="Apps">'.'</a>';
        break;
    } 
?>
```

#### 参考

[クエリ文字列とは｜URLパラメータ｜リクエストパラメータ - 意味/解説/説明/定義 ： IT用語辞典](http://e-words.jp/w/%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97.html)

Comment: &でつなぐ書き方は理解できたのですが、飛んだ先で各記事にidが取得できておりません。

Comment: @DaikiKojima これ以上は具体的なコードが提示されないとわかりませんが、各記事ということは複数のidを連携したいということでしょうか。もしそうであれば方法論自体が変わってきます。遷移元ページのphp、遷移先ページのapps.phpのコードを質問に追記してください。

Comment: apps.phpの追記をいたしました。